# How to ignore mapping a property of a list of objects

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using the MapStruct library to facilitate mapping between objects. I have a problem with the ignore not to map a certain property of some objects inside a list.

In object CompetitionEntity, I have this property list:

```
private List<GameEntity> games;
```

And in GameEntity, I have this

```
private TeamEntity visitorTeam;
```

When I go to do a mapping from CompetitionEntity to CopmpetitionDto, I want to ignore it mapping the object visitorTeam. I tried doing the following, but it doesn't work.

```
@Mapper
public interface CompetitionMapper {

@Mapping(target = "games.localTeam", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "games.visitorTeam", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "games.competition", ignore = true)
CompetitionDto entityToDto(CompetitionEntity entity);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options.

1. If such mapping rules should be always applied to `GameEntity`.

First define `GameMapper` with desired settings:

```java
@Mapper
public interface GameMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "localTeam", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "visitorTeam", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "competition", ignore = true)
    GameDto entityToDto(GameEntity entity);
}
```

Then in `CompetitionMapper` add `uses` parameter with link to `GameMapper` . That means `CompetitionMapper` will use methods from `GameMapper` when mapping `GameEntity`:

```java
@Mapper(uses = GameMapper.class)
public interface CompetitionMapper {

    CompetitionDto entityToDto(CompetitionEntity entity);

}
```

2. If such mapping should be applied to `GameEntity` only in context of `CompetitionEntity`.

Define a helper method in `CompetitionMapper` and use it with `quelifiedBy`.

```java
@Mapper
public interface CompetitionMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "games", qualifiedByName = "gameMapper")
    CompetitionDto entityToDto(CompetitionEntity entity);

    @Named("gameMapper")
    @Mapping(target = "localTeam", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "visitorTeam", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "competition", ignore = true)
    GameDto entityToDto(GameEntity entity);
}
```